# 307 http response on a ajax call with laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, .htaccess

I face an issue in my project with laravel 5.4 when I try to call a post request via Ajax. In my local host it perfectly works, but when I move my project to production server, it gives me an 307 response.

This is my code :

.htaccess File :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=307]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

function into the controller :

```
    public function switchVisiblity() {
    $id = request()->get('id');
    $property = Property::findOrFail($id);
    $property->isVisible = !$property->isVisible;
    $property->save();
    if (request()->ajax()) {
        return $property->isVisible+" ";
    }
    return redirect()->action('\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\HomeController@index');

}
```

Route definition in the web.php

```
    Route::post('/property/toggleVisiblity/', 'PropertyController@switchVisiblity');
```

Jquery Ajax code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.js-property-switchVisibility').click(function(){
    button = $(this);
    id = button.data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url : baseUrl + '/admin/property/toggleVisiblity/',
        data : {id: id, _token: _token},
        success:function(result){
            if(result=="1"){
                button.text("Hide");
                button.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');
            }else{
                button.text("Show")
                button.removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Error :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is in your question actually.

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=307]
```

You simply have to update your urls like so:

`'/admin/property/toggleVisiblity'` -- No trailing slash.